# jQuery target same id as class on mouse over

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add active class to #photo-desc li when mouseover on #photo-menu li.

```
$('#photo-menu li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
        var pClass = this.className;
        var pId = ('#photo-desc li').id;
        if (pClass == pId) {$('#photo-desc li').addClass('active');}
   });

<ul id="photo-menu">
    <li class="photo-1"><a href="">Photo 1</a></li>
    <li class="photo-2"><a href="">Photo 2</a></li>
    <li class="photo-3"><a href="">Photo 3</a></li>
    <li class="photo-4"><a href="">Photo 4</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="photo-desc">
    <li id="photo-1">Photo 1</li>
    <li id="photo-2">Photo 2</li>
    <li id="photo-3">Photo 3</li>
    <li id="photo-4">Photo 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Make fiddle and show us

Comment: @ask4tec is there anything wrong in my answer that doesn't suits your requirements ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you have class which has the same name with id's in your second one. So is pretty simple:

```js
$('#photo-menu li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
    var curClass = $(this).attr("class"); //take class
    if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
        $("#" + curClass).addClass("active"); //use class name to get the id in second list
    } else {
        $("#" + curClass).removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="photo-menu">
    <li class="photo-1"><a href="">Photo 1</a>

    </li>
    <li class="photo-2"><a href="">Photo 2</a>

    </li>
    <li class="photo-3"><a href="">Photo 3</a>

    </li>
    <li class="photo-4"><a href="">Photo 4</a>

    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="photo-desc">
    <li id="photo-1">Photo 1</li>
    <li id="photo-2">Photo 2</li>
    <li id="photo-3">Photo 3</li>
    <li id="photo-4">Photo 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the class to the element (ById), as easy as this:

```
$('#photo-menu li').on('mouseenter', function(){
        var class = $(this).attr('class');
        var pId = $('#'+class).addClass('active');}
});


$('#photo-menu li').on('mouseleave', function(){
        var class = $(this).attr('class');
        var pId = $('#'+class).removeClass('active');}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what do you want to do with the `var pId = ('#photo-desc li').id;`, but I also recomment to use jQuery.hover for this. There you can use `.addClass("active")` to set the active class on mouseover and with `each(function() {$( this ).removeClass("active");});` you can remove it on mouseout from all divs.

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gfobe/owvwrufo/1/ as example solution.

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nyL5aLLd/1/)**

jQuery `hover` itself attaches **two handlers :-**

- mouseenter
- mouseleave

[The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Still I would like to give this answer using the `hover handlers` as you are using the same .

```
 $('#photo-menu li').on('mouseenter', function () {
    var pClass = $(this).attr('class');

    $('#photo-desc li').each(function () {
      var pId = $(this).attr('id');

      if (pClass == pId) {
        $(this).addClass('active');   
        return;       
       }
    });
 }).on('mouseleave',function(){
        $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    });
```